# GroupOn - Material Design UI ListItem to Activity Animation Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, material-design, groupon

I am developing a mobile android app. Inside the GroupOn application, when the deals are listed inside of a ListView. If you click on a ListItem, there will be an animated transition into the newly launched Activity. How is this achieved? What library or API is being used? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate ImageView between two activities using shared element transitions with ChangeImageTransform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600239/animate-imageview-between-two-activities-using-shared-element-transitions-with-c)